# What is the correct way to upgrade a gae app under heavy load?

Tags: google-app-engine

Given that the default version of my app is under heavy load, what's the correct way to upgrade it to another version which is deployed but has 0 instances. The goal is to disturb traffic as little as possible.

One idea was to add resident instances to the non-default version but resident instances are only available to the default version of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One idea was to add resident instances to the non-default version but resident instances are only available to the default version of the app.

Yes, you're right. I think that a new App Engine feature named 'Servers' will be able to address your use case because you will be able to have resident instances on non-default versions (maybe I should say 'Servers' here). Now we're running Trusted Tester program for 'Servers'. Please see [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-appengine/vNrNnhAKcuk/discussion) if you're interested.

For now, the answer from Lipis is feasible (upvoted).

Comment: Lipis' answer is informative but not really helpful. At least this gives me a lead.

Answer (score 3):

If the version is deployed you can start the first instance by accessing through the direct link that looks like this:

```
http://version.example.appspot.com
```

After that I think you can easily switch to the new default version and I don't think that you will have any major (or at all) disturbances in your traffic. More instances will start booting up on demand as usual. Only the people that are going to initiate a new instance will have bigger latency but this is minor and acceptable compare to the total number of active users.

In general if you have issues with performance you can [adjust](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings) them based on your specific needs.